# Stripe Create subscription returns Status - Incomplete

Tags: .net-core, stripe-payments

I am using a testing card 4242424242424242.
I do not have its setting enabled - "Enable 3D Secure"

**EDIT**

Subcription Request Object

```
AddInvoiceItems: null
ApplicationFeePercent: null
BackdateStartDate: null
BillingCycleAnchor: null
BillingThresholds: null
CancelAt: null
CancelAtPeriodEnd: null
CollectionMethod: null
Coupon: null
Customer: "cus_IBn......."
DaysUntilDue: null
DefaultPaymentMethod: null
DefaultSource: null
DefaultTaxRates: null
Expand: null
ExtraParams: Count = 0
Items: Count = 1
Metadata: null
OffSession: null
PaymentBehavior: null
PendingInvoiceItemInterval: null
Plan: null
Prorate: false
ProrationBehavior: null
Quantity: null
TaxPercent: null
TransferData: null
TrialEnd: null
TrialFromPlan: null
TrialPeriodDays: null
```

Below is subscription object which I get as response after create subscription.
if this helps

> {
> "id": "sub_absc....",
> "object": "subscription",
> "application_fee_percent": null,
> "billing_cycle_anchor": 1602504785,
> "billing_thresholds": null,
> "cancel_at": null,
> "cancel_at_period_end": false,
> "canceled_at": null,
> "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
> "created": 1602504785,
> "current_period_end": 1605183185,
> "current_period_start": 1602504785,
> "customer": "cus_IBn....",
> "days_until_due": null,
> "default_payment_method": null,
> "default_source": null,
> "default_tax_rates": [],
> "discount": null,
> "ended_at": null,
> "items": {
> "object": "list",
> "data": [
> {
> "id": "si_IBn...",
> "object": "subscription_item",
> "billing_thresholds": null,
> "created": 1602504786,
> "metadata": {},
> "plan": {
> "id": "price_1HZu....",
> "object": "plan",
> "active": true,
> "aggregate_usage": null,
> "amount": 1500,
> "amount_decimal": 1500.0,
> "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
> "created": 1602146656,
> "currency": "usd",
> "interval": "month",
> "interval_count": 1,
> "livemode": false,
> "metadata": {},
> "nickname": null,
> "product": "prod_IAF....",
> "tiers": null,
> "tiers_mode": null,
> "transform_usage": null,
> "trial_period_days": null,
> "usage_type": "licensed"
> },
> "price": {
> "id": "price_1HZ.....",
> "object": "price",
> "active": true,
> "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
> "created": 1602146656,
> "currency": "usd",
> "livemode": false,
> "lookup_key": null,
> "metadata": {},
> "nickname": null,
> "product": "prod_IAFD1.....",
> "recurring": {
> "aggregate_usage": null,
> "interval": "month",
> "interval_count": 1,
> "trial_period_days": null,
> "usage_type": "licensed"
> },
> "tiers": null,
> "tiers_mode": null,
> "transform_quantity": null,
> "type": "recurring",
> "unit_amount": 1500,
> "unit_amount_decimal": 1500.0
> },
> "quantity": 1,
> "subscription": "sub_IBnU........",
> "tax_rates": []
> }
> ],
> "has_more": false,
> "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_IBn...."
> },
> "latest_invoice": "in_1Hb.........",
> "livemode": false,
> "metadata": {},
> "next_pending_invoice_item_invoice": null,
> "pause_collection": null,
> "pending_invoice_item_interval": null,
> "pending_setup_intent": null,
> "pending_update": null,
> "plan": {
> "id": "price_1HZu........",
> "object": "plan",
> "active": true,
> "aggregate_usage": null,
> "amount": 1500,
> "amount_decimal": 1500.0,
> "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
> "created": 1602146656,
> "currency": "usd",
> "interval": "month",
> "interval_count": 1,
> "livemode": false,
> "metadata": {},
> "nickname": null,
> "product": "prod_IAFD1k.......",
> "tiers": null,
> "tiers_mode": null,
> "transform_usage": null,
> "trial_period_days": null,
> "usage_type": "licensed"
> },
> "quantity": 1,
> "schedule": null,
> "start_date": 1602504785,
> "status": "incomplete",
> "tax_percent": null,
> "transfer_data": null,
> "trial_end": null,
> "trial_start": null
> }

Comment: The subscription will be incomplete if the initial payment failed or required authentication. What is the value of `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.status` , or the PaymentIntent's `last_payment_error` ? That should give a hint to why the payment failed and the subscription is incomplete.

Comment: subscription.latest_invoice is having the incoice Id and there is no payment_intent

Comment: The invoice and its PaymentIntent needs to be expanded or retrieved from the API, by default it's just an ID. It's described a bit at https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/fixed-price#create-subscription and the examples show `subscriptionOptions.AddExpand("latest_invoice.payment_intent");` for example for that reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @karllekko
*The invoice and its PaymentIntent needs to be expanded or retrieved from the API, by default it's just an ID. It's described a bit at stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/… and the examples show subscriptionOptions.AddExpand("latest_invoice.payment_intent"); for example for that reason.*

I am able to see the error and error was

> Non-INR transactions in India should have a shipping/billing address
> outside India. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/india-exports

I was using a dummy address for user since it is mandatory as per Indian gov.